# Email notification always taking system admin email

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a method which is always taking system admin email even if I log in with any other user. Here is an apex code:

```
public static void SendMail( string name){

        Id profileId=userinfo.getProfileId();
        String profileName=[Select Id,Name from Profile where Id=:profileId].Name;
        system.debug('ProfileName-->'+profileName);

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        string userName= UserInfo.getUserName();
        User activeUserInputFile = [Select Email From User where UserName = : userName AND ProfileId =:profileId limit 1];
        system.debug('Email1----->'+activeUserInputFile.Email);

        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {activeUserInputFile.Email};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject('Input file Notification.');
        mail.setPlainTextBody('File "'+name+'" has been processed.');
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailmessage[] {mail});
}
```

This method I am calling in my trigger.

Comment: Instead of this `activeUserInputFile.Email` why you don't use `userinfo.getuserEmail();`

Comment: @TusharSharma Or use setTargetObjectId and eliminate the daily mail limit usage.

Comment: @sfdcfox yes he can use that as well. That will be better option.

Comment: Still my problem is not resolved. If I put any email address in  setToAddresses also notification will be coming to admin.